# Emulador de NFC para android

Tags: java, android, emulador

Eu possuo um celular android sem NFC e preciso programar um aplicativo que manipule essa ferramenta. Existe algum emulador que simule o NFC no meu celular para que eu possa testar meus programas?

Answer (score 1):

A **NFC** - *Near Field Communication* - é uma tecnologia que permite a troca de informações entre dispositivos sem a necessidade de cabos ou fios, sendo necessária apenas uma aproximação física. Se seu celular **não possui** essa tecnologia, **não é possível** fazer uma transferência. Porém existem alguns softwares desktop que pode simular, como o [OPEN NFC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/).

Para mais detalhes [leia a documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html).

Veja o vídeo sobre [NFC & simulator OPEN NFC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Clw2rDCBmQw)<sup>(en)</sup> que é feito usando uma maquina virtual Android.